# Error In list: Unused argument (R Programming)

Tags: r

I am using MAC OS X Yosemite, and doing programming in RStudio.
I am facing problem with the lists, when ever i try to execute lists either on command line or in functions it gives me error something like this :-

```
> x <- list(1,2,3)
Error in list(1, 2, 3) : unused arguments (1, 2, 3)
> source("list1.r")
> list1()
Error in list(1, "a", TRUE, FALSE, 1 + (0+4i)) : 
  unused arguments (1, "a", TRUE, FALSE, 1 + (0+4i)).
```

Can anyone help me with this if its due to some Rstudio settings or OS problem or something else.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. My best guess is that you have created your own function called `list` that is masking the default, built-in version. I would bet anything that your first line will work fine in a clean R session.

Comment: Your guess is right Joran. Thank you. list worked when i cleared the workspace.